# Missing Aptana 3 update-url-list

Tags: url, aptana, aptana3

I have Aptana 3.1.3 standalone for Linux 64bit.

I want to update to 3.2.0 but there are no update urls in my perferences.

I used google but i only found update-urls for the eclipse plugin.

Can some one post me the url to update aptana.

Thanks
Cebor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name: Aptana Studio 3 Release Updates
location: http://download.aptana.com/studio3-rcp/plugin/update/